# OOP php file upload Invalid File Type

Tags: php

I'm on archlinux with Vagrant(hashicorp/precise32) i learn php from w3c-school, i'm on page upload file and here my script can't upload nothing the only thing return me is Invalid File ever (.jpg .png ecc..) here is the code:

```
class User 
{
    //init Db Variable
    private $db;

    /*
     * Constuctor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    /*
     * Upload User Avatar
     */
    public function uploadAvatar()
    {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "GIF", "jpeg", "JPEG", "jpg", "JPG", "png", "PNG");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]));

      if ((($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] === "image/gif") 
        || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] === "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] === "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] === "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] === "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] === "image/png")) && ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] < 20000000 ) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
            if ($_FILES["avatar"]["error"] > 0) {
                redirect('register.php', $_FILES["avatar"]["error"], 'error');
            } else {
                if (file_exists('img/avatars/' . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"])) {
                    redirect('register.php', 'File already exists', 'error');
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], 
                        "img/avatars/" . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);

                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            redirect('register.php', 'Invalid File Type!', 'error');
        }

    }
}
```

html fom Bootstap register

```
    <form ectype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="register.php">
        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="file" name="avatar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
        </div>
   </form>
```

register.php

```
<?php 
// Create User Object
$user = new User;

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
//Create Data away
$data = array();
  //Upload Avatar Image
      if ($user->uploadAvatar()) {
           return $data['avatar'] = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
       } else {
           $data['avatar'] = 'gavatarm.png';
    }
  }
```

Comment: check by print your `$_FILES`  , wat you get as a extension.

Comment: i have an empty array()

Comment: try with `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="register.php">` as below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Fix your typo, use **enctype** instead of **ectype**.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="register.php">
```

Comment: Happy to help, and warm welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)